# save image with face landmarks using dlib in python?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, dlib

Is there a way to save image with the overlay of facial landmarks with dlib using python? Because I've found only  the draw_rectangle function which is for c++!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the facial points, you can draw it on original image, like this:

```
def annotate_landmarks(im, landmarks):
    CIRCLE_SIZE = 1
    FONT_SCALE = 1
    THICKNESS_S = 1
    im = im.copy()
        #0-16: head
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks[0:17]):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        #cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos, fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, fontScale=FONT_SCALE, color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, CIRCLE_SIZE, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=THICKNESS_S)

    #17-21: left eye brow
    #22-26: right eye brow
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks[17:27]):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        #cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale=FONT_SCALE,color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, CIRCLE_SIZE, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=THICKNESS_S)

    #27-35: nose
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks[27:36]):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        #cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale=FONT_SCALE,color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, CIRCLE_SIZE, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=THICKNESS_S)

    #36-41: left eye
    #42-47: right eye
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks[36:48]):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        #cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale=FONT_SCALE,color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, CIRCLE_SIZE, color=(0, 255, 255), thickness=THICKNESS_S)

    #48-68: lips
    for idx, point in enumerate(landmarks[48:68]):
        pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
        #cv2.putText(im, str(idx), pos,fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX,fontScale=FONT_SCALE,color=(0, 0, 255))
        cv2.circle(im, pos, CIRCLE_SIZE, color=(255, 0, 255), thickness=THICKNESS_S)
    return im
```

Comment: This is the method I would use too, but you should point out you're using the opencv-python library as well as dlib. I'm not sure the person that asked the question has both installed.

Comment: Actually, I have it.. :) I also use them both !

Comment: Cool, glad it helped :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked for me.

```
.....................
shape = predictor(img, d)
vec= np.empty([68,2], dtype=int)
for b in range(68):
    vec[b][0] = shape.part(b).x
    vec[b][1] = shape.part(b).y

 landmarks_img=annotate_landmarks(img,vec)
 cv2.imwrite("landmarked-"+os.path.basename(f),landmarks_img) #save image
```

where I made this change to **annotate_landmarks()**

```
pos = (point[0], point[1])
```

***instead of :***

```
pos = (point[0, 0], point[0, 1])
```